# Owner Draw Combo Box display messed up while scrolling on Windows 7

Tags: .net, winforms

When the the combo contains lots of items, the combo is dropped down and you scroll the drop down list up and down, the items in the drop down get all messed up - it looks like they are overwriting each other. I am running on 64 bit windows 7 with deve studio 2008. I didn't have this problem on windows xp. Have reduced the code to a simple example which reproduces the problem.

```
 public class ODComboBox : ComboBox
 {
    protected override void OnDrawItem(
        DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Index == -1)  {
            e.DrawBackground();
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
            return;
        }

        string text = Items[e.Index].ToString();       
        e.Graphics.SetClip(e.Bounds);
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.Graphics.DrawString(text, Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), e.Bounds);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();          
    }
}
```

The draw mode of the comob is set to OwnerDrawFixed and here is the OnLoad method from the host from.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
       cobmob1.Items.Add("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
       cobmob1.Items.Add("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB");
    }

    cobmob1.DropDownWidth = 500;
}
```

[image: combo screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, after a video driver update, that was corrected.

Comment: I downloaded the latest driver from the Nvidia site and this fixed the problem - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**I'm unable to reproduce the behavior that you described using the above code under Windows Server 2008 R2, 64-bit. The scrolling seems smooth to me, although it's a slightly unusual effect to see the same two items repeated over and over in the list.** I very much doubt the cause is something that is present in Windows 7 but doesn't manifest itself in the server variant of the same; they're essentially identical operating systems.

My guess is it's related to your video card drivers and the new display model ([WDDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Display_Driver_Model)) introduced in Windows Vista. Perhaps some sort of redrawing problem? How old is your video card? Did you upgrade that at the same time you upgraded from Windows XP?

It could also be related to the new Aero theme. Have you tried running your application under the Aero Basic or Classic themes? If you don't want to change your OS theme, try this:

1. Right-click on your application's .EXE file, and select "Properties" from the drop-down menu.
2. Open the "Compatibility" tab.
3. Check the "Disable visual themes" and "Disable desktop composition" boxes.
4. Click OK, and then run the application again.

Comment: I think you are on the right track - setting the theme on the machine to Aero basic or Classic solved the problem. The settings on the .exe however had no effect. My machine os quite a recent - its a Dell T3500 precision with an Nvidea display FX580 display card and it came with widows 7 installed. I'm happy to use Aero Basic on my machine (actually think I prefer it) but I need to run my code on machines that I can't control. Any idea how I can make my code safe to run on Aero? Begining to think its a plot to force me to migrate to WPF :-)

Comment: @Shane - did you try to draw background manually instead of e.DrawBackground();

Comment: @Code Gray - I'd like accept your answer but I need to find a solution which allow the code runs on the most default configuration or at least confirm that this is not possible. Any ideas for other things to try or sources of information I can investigate?

Comment: @Shane: I actually have to install Windows 7 tonight on a machine, so I was already planning on checking to see if it's behavior is any different. Otherwise, I haven't updated my answer because I honestly don't have any other ideas on what could be causing this. It's very strange that I can't recreate the behavior. Before I try it again, I just want to make sure that you're that you're using the exact code from your original question, and this is all that's required to reproduce the behavior on your machine?

Comment: @Shane: So tonight turned into a day or so later, but I can't see any painting issues on a fresh Windows 7 32-bit install, under the Aero theme. I've tried running the app compiled in Debug and Release mode, as well as on comboboxes with the `DropDownStyle` set to "DropDown" and "DropDownList". I even tried setting the `FlatStyle` to "Standard" and "System". I really don't know what you're seeing. The scroll looks perfectly smooth to me (aside from the slightly weird effect created by the specific test strings). I'm sorry that I can't reproduce it, because if not I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Code Gray: Thanks for your efforts, much appreciated. Will give it a few more days and accept your answer if I don't get a complete solution. I suspect there may not be one - maybe its just broken on my setup. Perhaps its fairly rare - need to check a few machines. Will try the Microsoft forums. Will check the code but I think what I posted shoud be it. Will also try the setting you mentioned above and try some on my graphics card. Do you know if its possible to post a image so I can provide a screenshot?

Comment: @Shane: You can definitely post screen shots. Just edit your question using the link at the bottom, and add an image. There's an icon that looks sort of like an image at the top of the editing field. It will upload from your computer and use a free image hosting service automatically.

Comment: @Code Gray- Sorry its taken me so long to get arround to accepting your answer - I got distracted with other things and kinda forgot about it. Have attached a screenshot in case you are interested to see how it looks on my machine.

Comment: @Shane: Hrmm, looking at your screenshot, the first thing that pops into my mind is fonts. What locale are you in? What's your default GUI font? I was trying to replicate the behavior with Segoe UI, but it looks like you might be using one of the international fonts?

Comment: I accpeted the answer below as this turned out to be the fix in the end but have voted up your answer as you have provided much useful info. I am a bit suprised that a driver issue could affect owner drawn controls but not standard ones.

Comment: @Shane: Well I'm glad you got it solved. I guessed it was related to the video card drivers; I didn't realize you hadn't already tried updating the drivers.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution from here:
 https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/524617/listbox-ownerdraw-windows-7
put this code in OnDrawItem instead of e.DrawBackground
Posted by Mykola Kovalchuk on 1/2/2010 at 9:01 μμ
I have found working solution – special double cleaning of background (both lines are required and in exactly this order):

```
//e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(e.BackColor), e.Bounds);
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, e.BackColor.R, e.BackColor.G, e.BackColor.B)), e.Bounds);
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, e.BackColor.R, e.BackColor.G, e.BackColor.B)), e.Bounds);
```

I think ListBox in Windows 7 paints itself with transparent colors, and on scrolling it does not clear part to be repainted, which leads to painting artefacts.
Also e.BackColor is named color "Window", and its is not equal to generated by FromArgb even if all ARGB components are same.